# confusion over `Teacher.prototype.constructor = Teacher` and why it is important

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype

I'm currently studying javascript inheritance on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Inheritance) and have encountered the following paragraphs.

[image]

After setting `Teacher.prototype` to `Person.prototype` (i.e. conceptually, `Teacher` inherit from `Person`), the author said that it is important to set `Teacher.prototype.constructor` to `Teacher`, otherwise it can become a problem.

But the author did not expand on what the problem is. And when I **didn't** set `Teacher.prototype.constructor = Teacher`, everything worked just fine.

Could someone please explain to me what exactly is the problem? And why everything worked just fine even if I didn't set `Teacher.prototype.constructor = Teacher`?

Comment: It's just a formality in order to obey the standards for what `constructor` is supposed to be. In my experience, `constructor` is used very rarely, so it's not all that important for it to be accurate.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense. Thanks 4castile and Jan for helping out!

Comment: @Jan `Object.create(myTeacherInstance)` doesn't make a new instance of `Teacher`, it would make a new object whose prototype object is `myTeacherInstance`, also, I think you may have meant `new (new Teacher().constructor)()`

Comment: Yes you're right  I meant  `new myTeacherInstance.constructor()` and `Object.create(myTeacherInstance.constructor.prototype)` which would both return new instances of type `Person`. And the third case I mentioned (comparison) would be `myTeacherInstance.constructor === Teacher` or `myTeacherInstance instanceof Teacher` which in this case would then return false

Comment: oh wow, javascript IS confusing

Comment: Yeah I'm removing my first comment, it just made everything more confusing.

Comment: @Jan You'd use `Object.create(Object.getPrototypeOf(myTeacherInstance))` anyway, and no, `myTeacherInstance instanceof Teacher` works regardless of any `.constructor` property

Comment: Yeah you're right `instanceof` would still return true because it goes up the entire prototype chain